# New Molly babies

Tags: aquarium, fish, breeding

I bought a Dalmatian Molly today. She is the only fish on the tank. She’s only been in her tank 5 hours and I just got home and found 3 babies. Stores are closed as it’s late Sunday night. What do I do until I can get to a store in the morning. I do have a small 1-2 gallon tank currently not being used. Is she done having babies? I’ve had fish my whole life but this is the first Molly I bought!

Comment: do you have plants or decorations where the fry can hide in your tank? you can use a number of objects to make a safe place for the babies like a small upside down plate with a tiny opening under so the fry can pass but not their mother.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it too much. If the fry have a place to hide (like Trond mentioned) they should be fine. I have a tank of platies and have had no issues with the majority of them maturing, with only standard tank decorations.